# Совместимость ForeignKey и PrimaryKey

Tags: yii, миграция, mysql

Необходимо создать таблицу `attribute_has_good` где поля `good_id` и `attribute_id` будут являться первичным ключом(совместно), а так же внешними ключами к другим таблицам. Пишу миграцию:

```
 class m000000_000000_attribute_base extends CDbMigration
{

public function safeUp()
{
    $this->createTable('{{attribute_attribute}}', array(
            'id' => 'pk',
            'name' => 'varchar(250) NOT NULL',
            'type_id' => 'integer DEFAULT NULL',
        ), ''
    );

    $this->createTable('{{attribute_has_good}}', array(
            'good_id' => 'int NOT NULL',
            'attribute_id' => 'int NOT NULL',
            'value' => 'varchar(250) NOT NULL',
            'PRIMARY KEY (`good_id`, `attribute_id`)',
        ), ''

    $this->createTable('{{attribute_type}}', array(
            'id' => 'pk',
            'name' => 'varchar(250) NOT NULL',
        ), ''
    );

$this->addForeignKey("fk_{{attribute_attribute}}_type", '{{attribute_attribute}}', 'type_id', '{{attribute_type}}', 'id', 'SET NULL', 'NO ACTION');
$this->addForeignKey("fk_{{attribute_has_good}}_good", '{{attribute_has_good}}', 'good_id', '{{catalog_good}}', 'id', 'SET NULL', 'NO ACTION');

}
}
```

но получаю ошибку

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'unishop.#sql-1d1d_80' (errno: 150). The SQL statement executed was: ALTER TABLE `yupe_attribute_has_good` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_yupe_attribute_has_good_good` FOREIGN KEY (`good_id`) REFERENCES `yupe_catalog_good` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION (/opt/bitnami/apps/demo/htdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:358)
```

Причем создание внешнего ключа `fk_{{attribute_attribute}}_type` ошибки не вызывает.

Не могу понять как осуществить задуманное...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. PK здесь не при чем...
Я устанавливаю ON DELETE SET NULL для поля NOT NULL. Надо так:

```
$this->addForeignKey("fk_{{attribute_has_good}}_good", '{{attribute_has_good}}', 'good_id', '{{catalog_good}}', 'id', 'NO ACTION', 'NO ACTION');
```